# JPA: how to persist many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these 2 entity with many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "languages")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

I already have 20 languages saved in my language table. Now, I want to create a user and give relate that user with first language in the language table. So I did something like this

```
    Language selectedLanguage = languageService.findById(1);
    stammdaten.getLanguages().add(selectedLanguage);
    stammdatenService.save(stammdaten);
```

But this gives me error `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.outgoing.Entity.Language`. So how can I save this many to many relation. One thing to note here: I don't want to add new language. I want to add new user with already created languages.

Comment: There's something wrong in your code I think... The User entity should have List<Language> instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `CascadeType.ALL` with `CascadeType.MERGE`.

Also, add setters on both entities.

Comment: your solution works but I don't understand why. I thought  `CascadeType.ALL` covers all like merge, persisting etc

Answer (score 4):

I define many to many relation through @ManyToMany annotation in JPA.

I have written a code example to insert.

I think this image will help you understand

[image]

Comment: What if you want to do that with a controller ?

Comment: You need to write a service for the DAO layer and then inject the service into the controller layer.

Comment: OK. Thanks! But if I want to pull out the object from the view instead of hardcoding the Course(Course course = ... Course("Jee") and Student (Student student = ... Student("Ali")) from the same form. Can I do that in one Session ?

Comment: public void insertStudentAndCourseManyToMany( Student[] students, Course[] courses )
 {
  for ( Course course : courses )
  {
   em.persist( course );
   for ( Student student : students )
   {
    student.addCourse( course );
    em.persist( student );
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks. But in the controller. Using model attribute. Maybe I have to make a wrapped class as I will have two objects backing a form.